# Kubernetes port forward for django

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster in which in one of the docker container I am running django.
It is listening on port 8999

http://0.0.0.0:8999

Whereas the service is listening on port 8444

I need to access django admin from outside so I did port forward

kubectl port-forward service/django-service 8444:8444

But it is not loading the page. I am not sure if I should port forward the 8444 or 8999.
Please advise.

Comment: kubectl port-forward service/django-service 8444:8999

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful.  If you `kubectl port-forward service/...` you need to use the service's port, not the service's target port (the pod's port); based on the prose, that `port-forward` invocation looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say your django app is running in a container inside a pod naming -
'django-75f59d57f4-4nd6q'

Verify that the django-75f59d57f4-4nd6q  is running in the Pod, and listening on port 8999

```
kubectl get pod django-75f59d57f4-4nd6q --template='{{(index (index .spec.containers 0).ports 0).containerPort}}{{"\n"}}'
```

If you get - 8999 in the result

and if you want to port-forward it to 8444
do this -

```
kubectl port-forward django-75f59d57f4-4nd6q 8444:8999
```

and if you have named the service as django-service as then do

```
kubectl port-forward service/django-service 8444:8999
```